# ngInfinitescroll is not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Trying to load the data while scrolling using the ngInifinitescroll but it is not working for some reason. what would be my mistake?

```
Experts inputs please. Here it is my work.


http://jsfiddle.net/a6rv04pu/2/
```

Comment: @JasonAller don't copy-paste code from JSFiddle into the question: [see meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/6296561)

Comment: It seems two problem with the fiddle. 1. only works if angular is 1.4 and set to load at `body buttom` so it will load after the ng-infinite-scroll is loaded. 2. `vm` is not defined.